# Angular Form validation is not working when two text box inside one form group

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to do angular form validation am not getting error message when i click on submit, i have added two text two receive to take first name and last name  what went wrong i couldn't find please let me know

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="resources/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"     rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="resources/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="resources/sb-admin/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Date picker css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/datepicker/datepicker.min.css"></link>

<!-- My css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/mine/css/MyCss.css"></link>

<script src="resources/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/app/app.js"></script>


</head> 
 <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <%@ include file="Menu.jsp" %>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h3 class="page-header"><b>Student Enrollment</b></h3>
                    </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                     Basic Information for admin
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                             <div class="form-body">  <!-- flot-chart previus class name -->                            

                            <form id="userForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="login" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

                                         <!-- NAME -->


                                  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.terms.$invalid && (userForm.terms.$dirty || submitted)}">
                                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Full Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                 <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-required="true">
                                                 <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your First Name is required.</p>
                                            </div>  
                                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-required="true">
                                                 <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your Last Name is required.</p>
                                            </div>                                          
                                        </div>








                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-1 ">
                                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="rstbutton">Refresh</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel -->
                </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->      

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
        <script src="resources/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src="resources/sb-admin/sb-admin-2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set name for `form` like to this  `name="userForm"`

```
 <form name="userForm">
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="" >
   <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your Last Name is required.</p>
   <input type="text" name="firsname" ng-model=""  >
   <p ng-show="userForm.firstname.$error.required && (userForm.firstname.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your First Name is required.</p>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code changes need to be made **:**

- `ng-model` for both the text boxes should be different. In your code it is looking like same for both inputs.
- `name` attribute value should be different if you want to perform different validations on both the fields.

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myController',function( $scope ) { 
  $scope.validate = function() {
    alert('submitting..');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app= "myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="userForm.$valid && validate()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="Your Name" ng-required="true">
                <p ng-show="submitted == true && userForm.firstname.$error.required" class="help-block">Your First Name is required.</p>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="Your Name" ng-required="true">
                <p ng-show="submitted == true && userForm.lastname.$error.required" class="help-block">Your Last Name is required.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted = true"/>
    </form>
</div>
```